# how to efficiently deal with multitude of iframes in dynamic html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, extjs

So I have a large amount of html that is served up by a web service that i need to display. The problem is the this html very often contains many iframe links to youtube videos. I've counted one that contained around 20.

These are not small amounts of html and I'm trying to weigh efficiency here. Right now those 20 iframes are slowing the app down to a crawl.

What would be more efficient? Stopping the iframes from loading ( which I'm unsure of how to do)

-or-

Parse through the html and remove the iframes and replacing them with the link to the video within them, thus allowing the user to open up the video, but not having to worry about the iframe. This can be done before they are displayed and may increase load time a bit, but would reduce http calls (i think)

-or-

Any suggestions?

Thanks

(Also I am not using JQuery nor is it available)

Answer (score 0):

So here is the method i found works somewhat. Only problem is I've noticed on iframes nested deeply within tables it will not always find them, if someone has an alternative method please let me know.

```
parseMessage: function(json) {
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      container.id = 'tempContainer';
      document.body.appendChild(container);
      container.innerHTML = json[4];
      var iframes = container.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
      if (iframes.length != 0)
      {
        for (var a = 0; a < iframes.length; a += 1) {
            var sourcetemp = iframes[a].src;
            var parent = iframes[a].parentNode;
            var newNode = document.createElement('a');
            newNode.href = sourcetemp;
            newNode.innerHTML = sourcetemp;
            parent.removeChild(iframes[a]);
            parent.appendChild(newNode);
        }
      }
      document.body.removeChild(container);
      return container.innerHTML;
      //mydiv = json[4].getElementById('FirstDiv');
      //while ( mydiv.firstChild ) mydiv.removeChild( mydiv.firstChild );
  },
```